# Mock GraphQLUpload dataype in POSTMAN

Tags: graphql, postman

I am using Postman to send GraphQL queries to my graphQL server. This is what a particular mutation schema looks like:

```
extend type Mutation {
    createMutation(
      my_id: ID!
      my_data: input_data
    ): some_output


input input_data {
    some_key: int
    file : Upload!
}
```

I am able to perform other mutations and query through graphQL by defining appropriate GraphQL variables in here
[image]

I am not sure how to create a json value in GraphQL Variables for "file" of type Upload

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec

Comment: @xadm how can I do this when the mutation doesnt have ($file) parameter but instead has it in one of its input fields like the example taken above. I will have to mock input_data and then mock file : Upload ! in it

Comment: first of all ... use variables !!! e.g. `$my_data` of `input_data` (use CamelCase!!) type, `file` is a prop of the passed object

Comment: @xadm I cannot change the server schema, the server is defined similar to how I have defined the snippet. How should I solve this issue?
"variables" arent defined in my server schema

Comment: using variables doesn't change the schema ... learn basic graphql usage first? https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: @xadm I am reading about variables thank you! Would it be possible to get a sample operations and variable map for the case I have described?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239296/discussion-between-sid-anand-and-xadm).